# A semiprime right semihereditary ring R is right isonoetherian or right uniform if and only if it is right nei-Noetherian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, module-isomorphism

I need to prove this theorem, but I guess I need some hints since I cannot even imagine how it can be proved. By the way, it is known that if $R$ is isonoetherian, then it is nei-Noetherian. The followings are the definitions of some terms in the theorem:

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be a right $R$-module. $M$ is called $\textbf{isonoetherian}$ if, for every ascending chain $M_1 \leq M_2 \leq \cdots$ of submodules of $M$, it can be found an index $n$ $\geq1$  such that $M_n \cong M_i$ for every $i$ $\geq$ $n$. If $R_R$ is isonoetherian, then $R$ is a right isonoetherian ring.

An $R$-module $M$ is called $\textbf{nei-Noetherian}$ if for all ascending chains $M_1 \leq M_2 \leq \cdots$ of non-essential submodules of M, there can be found an index $n$ such that $M_i \cong M_n$, for each $i \geq n$.

Comment: Is this question a contender to a contest of squeezing a maximum number of scary adjectives into a title?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right, but this is the original statement from the paper "Some variants of ascending and descending chain conditions" by A.K.Chaturvedi and S.Prakash. The terms whose definitions are given above are also new for me, especially the second one and I cannot combine all these terms with each other for now.

Comment: What does the paper say exactly with regards to this statement? It's a little fishy that you "have to prove" something out of the paper that sounds a lot like one of the paper's main results. Are you saying the article leaves it as an exercise?

Comment: Some new terms and results in this article are about my master thesis subject so that I try to understand and prove almost every statement there. So, I do not have to prove this but if I can understand or at least imagine how it can be proved, then I will write this one in my thesis with the proof. By the way, in this article, this theorem is stated without any proof.